# Restrict movement of layer in Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Is there a way to block the movement of a layer in photoshop and still be able to do editing in the same layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to select lock position (the one with the arrows) in the layers palette:

[image]